# How to create a static website from MBOX file

Tags: csv, javascript, json, mbox

I have a large MBOX file (16000 emails) from a public email group which is now closed. For archival and research purposes, I would like to serve these emails on a website. How can I go about accomplishing this?

I downloaded an MBOX viewer on Windows which lets me create HTML and EML files but I am not sure how I can read this data using JavaScript and display in a tabular format on a web page.

I tried exporting these emails to JSON and used the `fetch` command to display data in table format. But this approach works for plain text. Most emails have custom formatting without which the content is difficult to follow.

So in short I am looking for a way to create a simple web page where users can filter for date, sender, email subject, or email content (4 columns of the table) using the MBOX or HTML/EML files for each email.

Comment: You may want to try using Python. There is library [mailbox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html) that could be useful. You could use Django to build the web app, or just use mailbox/Python to dump the data into a database and use whatever platform you prefer to build the UI.